# Need to do Ebook management Sytem in VB, What should i do as a newbie?

Tags: vb.net

i want to to create a ebook management system in VB. This is for my university purposes, i dont have any idea about VB.net, so kindly i ask you to give any tutorial link. And these all should be in the project.

> The app should be connected to
>   database
>
> The user can search for the book in
>   the databases

The main thing is i want to know simple ways to work with databases. So kindly give some links for these, or even the project source code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hb2a397.aspx).
You should probably buy a book.

Comment: No i just need link that just starts from scratch and build any application say stock management. So that i can learn and modify according to my project!